# What are better ways to create a method that takes many arguments? (10+?)

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

I was looking at some code of a fellow developer, and almost cried. In the method definition there are 12 arguments. From my experience..this isn't good. If it were me, I would have sent in an object of some sort.

Is there another / more preferred way to do this (in other words, what's the best way to fix this and explain why)?

```
public long Save (
    String today, 
    String name, 
    String desc, 
    int ID, 
    String otherNm, 
    DateTime dt, 
    int status, 
    String periodID, 
    String otherDt, 
    String submittedDt
)
```

**ignore my poor variable names - they are examples**

Comment: Are the arguments related in some way? If so, then group them in an object that describes the semantic. Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought this was a reasonable question, why are there two votes to close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It highly depends on the language.

In a language without compile-time typechecking (e.g. python, javascript, etc.) you should use **keyword arguments** (common in python: you can access them like a dictionary passed in as an argument) or **objects/dictionaries** you manually pass in as arguments (common in javascript).

However the "argument hell" you described is sometimes "the right way to do things" for certain languages with compile-time typechecking, because using objects will obfuscate the semantics from the typechecker. The solution then would be to use a **better language** with compile-time typechecking which allows pattern-matching of objects as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use objects. Also, the function is probably doing too much if it needs all of this information, so use smaller functions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complex the function is. If it does something non-trivial with each of those arguments, it should probably be split. If it just passes them through, they should probably be collected in an object. But if it just creates a row in a table, it's not really big deal. It's less of a deal if your language supports keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use objects.

```
class User { ... }
User user = ...
Save(user);
```

It decision provides easy way for adding new parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the issue you're experiencing is being able to look at the method call and know what argument is receiving what value. This is a pernicious problem in a language like Java, which lacks something like keyword arguments or JSON hashes to pass named arguments.

In this situation, the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is a useful solution. It's more objects, three total, but leads to more comprehensible code for the problem you're describing. So the three objects in this case would be as such:

1. **Thing**: stateful entity, typically immutable (i.e. getters only)
2. **ThingBuilder**: factory class, creates a Thing entity and sets its values.
3. **ThingDAO**: not necessary for using the Builder pattern, but addresses your question.

**Interaction**

```
/* 
ThingBuilder is a static inner class of Thing, where each of its 
"set" method calls returns the ThingBuilder instance being worked with
while the final "build()" call returns the instantiated Thing instance.
*/
Thing thing = Thing.createBuilder().
                .setToday("2012/04/01")
                .setName("Example")
                // ...etc...
                .build();

// the Thing instance as get methods for each property
thing.getName();

// get your reference to thingDAO however it's done
thingDAO.save(thing);
```

The result is you get named arguments and an immutable instance.